# Loopback: app is undefined

Tags: loopbackjs

I am having a custom script in server/middleware/robots.js with the following content:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.get('/robots.txt', function (req, res) {
    res.type('text/plain');

    if (app.settings.env === 'production') {
      res.send("User-agent: *\nAllow: /");
    } else {
      res.send("User-agent: *\nDisallow: /");
    }
  });
};
```

However I am getting the error message that app is undefined.

I tried adding the following line at the bottom of server.js:

```
module.exports = app;
```

but no luck.

When I remove the module.exports line and require app from ../server I get the following error:

```
[2018-07-07T09:51:30.077Z] error: uncaughtException: Middleware factory must be a function
```

How do I access app outside server.js? I followed the documentation closely but I am not able to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Try importing the server.js into your robot.js file

```
    const app = require('../server.js')
```

And also export your app in server.js

```
`   const loopback = require('loopback');` 

    const app = module.exports = loopback();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried to import the server?

```js
const app = require('../server')

module.exports = function() {
  app.get('/robots.txt', function (req, res) {
    res.type('text/plain');

    if (app.settings.env === 'production') {
      res.send("User-agent: *\nAllow: /");
    } else {
      res.send("User-agent: *\nDisallow: /");
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: im getting the following error: AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: "handler" must be a function at Function.proto.middleware (/my-project-folder/node_modules/loopback/lib/server-app.js:178:3)